# security issue of key generation in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I recently went to settings in Google Chrome in Settings -> Advanced -> Content settings and under "Key generation" it had an option "Do not allow any site to use key generation in forms (recommended)"

I can't wrap my head around why it is recommended not to use key generation. I have a basic idea of what cryptography is and I can't understand how using key generation could be a risk. From my understanding of the topic, key generation can be used for public key cryptography and things like signing. How does that pose a security risk?

Comment: I also saw that recently. I presume this has something to do with the `<keygen>` element, which is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/keygen) by now. That's probably the reason for that recommendation. Still, I'm just thinking aloud. Anyway, this question is better suited for [security.se] or [su].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [IT security](http://security.stackexchange.com).